# Keras - Difference between categorical_accuracy and sparse_categorical_accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

What is the difference between `categorical_accuracy` and `sparse_categorical_accuracy` in Keras? There is no hint in the [documentation for these metrics](https://keras.io/metrics/), and by asking Dr. Google, I did not find answers for that either.

The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/metrics.py):

```
def categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.cast(K.equal(K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1),
                          K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)),
                  K.floatx())


def sparse_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.cast(K.equal(K.max(y_true, axis=-1),
                          K.cast(K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1), K.floatx())),
                  K.floatx())
```

Comment: Maybe this can help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43546939/3374996 . Something to do with targets. I am not sure if by targets they mean the y_true, y_pred are sparse or the output of categorical accuracy is sparse.

Comment: Pretty bad that this isn't in the docs nor the docstrings.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/0bc8fac4463c68faa3b3c415c26eab02aa361fd5/keras/metrics.py#L24)

```
def categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.cast(K.equal(K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1),
                          K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)),
                  K.floatx())


def sparse_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.cast(K.equal(K.max(y_true, axis=-1),
                          K.cast(K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1), K.floatx())),
K.floatx())
```

`categorical_accuracy` checks to see if the *index* of the maximal true value is equal to the *index* of the maximal predicted value.

`sparse_categorical_accuracy` checks to see if the maximal true value is equal to the *index* of the maximal predicted value.

From Marcin's answer above the `categorical_accuracy` corresponds to a `one-hot` encoded vector for `y_true`.

Comment: Aren't we passing integers instead of one-hot vectors in sparse mode? why then it takes the maximum in the line K.max(y_true, axis=-1) ?? :/ shouldn't there be only one value in y_true I mean?

Answer (score 90):

So in `categorical_accuracy` you need to specify your target (`y`) as one-hot encoded vector (e.g. in case of 3 classes, when a true class is second class, `y` should be `(0, 1, 0)`. In `sparse_categorical_accuracy` you need should only provide an integer of the true class (in the case from previous example - it would be `1` as classes indexing is `0`-based).

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I think you are wrong in your terminology - in sparse categorical accuracy you do not **need** to provide an integer - instead you **may** provide an array of length one with the index only - since keras chooses the max value from the array - but you may also provide an array of any length - for example of three results - and keras will choose the maximum value from this array and check if it corresponds to the index of the max value in y_pred

Comment: @aviv Follow up question - how is this different from just "accuracy"? Thanks.

Comment: @user3303020 when you tell keras to use `"accuracy"` keras is using the default accuracy which is `categorical_accuracy`

Comment: If you look at https://keras.io/api/metrics/accuracy_metrics/#accuracy-class, I think categorical_accuracy require label to be one hot encoded, while for accuracy the label can't be one hot encoded. My own tests confirms this.

Answer (score 17):

The `sparse_categorical_accuracy` expects **sparse targets**:

```
[[0], [1], [2]]
```

For instance:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sparse = [[0], [1], [2]]
logits = [[.8, .1, .1], [.5, .3, .2], [.2, .2, .6]]

sparse_cat_acc = tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()
sparse_cat_acc(sparse, logits)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.6666666666666666>
```

---

`categorical_accuracy` expects **one hot encoded targets**:

```
[[1., 0., 0.],  [0., 1., 0.], [0., 0., 1.]]
```

For instance:

```
onehot = [[1., 0., 0.],  [0., 1., 0.], [0., 0., 1.]]
logits = [[.8, .1, .1], [.5, .3, .2], [.2, .2, .6]]

cat_acc = tf.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
cat_acc(sparse, logits)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.6666666666666666>
```

Answer (score 0):

One difference that I just hit is the difference in the name of the metrics.

with `categorical_accuracy`, this worked:

```
mcp_save_acc = ModelCheckpoint('model_' + 'val_acc{val_accuracy:.3f}.hdf5', save_best_only=True, monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max')
```

but after switching to `sparse_categorical accuracy`, I now need this:

```
mcp_save_acc = ModelCheckpoint('model_' + 'val_acc{val_sparse_categorical_accuracy:.3f}.hdf5', save_best_only=True, monitor='val_sparse_categorical_accuracy', mode='max')
```

even though I still have `metrics=['accuracy']` as an argument to my `compile()` function.

I kind of wish `val_acc` and/or `val_accuracy` just worked for all keras' inbuilt `*_crossentropy` losses.

Comment: This is interesting, useful and of practical value, but not related to the question. It should at best be a comment.