# Selecting validation metric for `categorical_crossentropy` in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, cross-entropy

I am looking at these two questions and documentation:

[Whats the output for Keras categorical_accuracy metrics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56208659/whats-the-output-for-keras-categorical-accuracy-metrics)

[Categorical crossentropy need to use categorical_accuracy or accuracy as the metrics in keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544358/categorical-crossentropy-need-to-use-categorical-accuracy-or-accuracy-as-the-met)

https://keras.io/api/metrics/probabilistic_metrics/#categoricalcrossentropy-class

For classification of X-Rays images I (15 classes) I do:

```
# Compile a model
model1.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', 
metrics = ['accuracy']) 

# Fit the model
history1 = model1.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs = 10, 
steps_per_epoch = 10, verbose = 1, validation_data = valid_generator)
```

My model works and I have an output:

[image]

But I am not sure how to add validation accuracy here to compare results and avoid over/underfitting.

Comment: Doesn't it show the validation accuracy at the epoch end?

Comment: I am not sure, it is slow after the first epoch.

Comment: @Frightera, you were right, my first epoch was super slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope the following can help you:

The use of `"categorical_crossentropy"` tells me that your labels are a one hot encoding over different classes.

Let's say you have 15 classes, the correct prediction would be a vector with 14 zeros, and a one at the corresponding index. In this context `"accuracy"` will be very high as your model will be correctly predicting mostly zero everywhere, so the accuracy should easily be at least 13/15 = 0.86.

A more suitable metric would be `"categorical_accuracy"` which will give you 1 if the model predicts the correct index, and else 0.

If you have a validation `"categorical_accuracy"` better than 1/15 = 0.067 (assuming your class are correctly balanced), your model is better than random.

You can find a list of metrics at [keras metrics](https://keras.io/api/metrics/).

Comment: Thanks! What would you recommend if I have 60000 data points with 14 classes of medical findings (some problems) and 1 class as No finding. Data is balanced 50%-50% approximately in this competition https://www.kaggle.com/c/vinbigdata-chest-xray-abnormalities-detection

Comment: In this context it would be interesting to separate these two cases. If you have enough time, perhaps you could try to create a custom accuracy metric for each of these two cases [see here](https://keras.io/api/metrics/#creating-custom-metrics). If not, your model will be better than random when `categorical_accuracy > 0.5`.